# Facebook: count number of unique users who shared a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to GET number of unique users who shared a post on a facebook fan page, remotely?
Basically I want to post a status update on my fan page. Next, for each time a fan shares the post, I want the count (of users who shared the post) to be updated on a separate web page. I know it's possible to get number of likes for a post, but how do I get the number of UNIQUE users who shared a post?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with insights:

```
/PAGE_ID/insights?metric=page_storytellers_by_story_type
```

From what it looks like on my pages the `user post` value is the number of unique shares. The documentation isn't really clear on this though, so YMMV.